# Very strange issue with php $_SESSION var

Tags: php, algorithm

Maybe I am too tired... but I can't figure out how the session id in this piece of code becomes 143 from 149.

```
echo "session id is".$_SESSION['userid'];
$smarty->assign('itemresults',$arr2);

$_SESSION['userid']

if (isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
    $userid=$_REQUEST['id'];
}
else
{
echo "session id 1 is".$_SESSION['userid'];
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
}
echo "session id 2 is".$_SESSION['userid'];
```

Output:

```
session id is149session id 2 value is143
```

UPDATE:

Ok just found out that If I change the var $userid the issue is no more but why assigning a value to $userid will modify $_SESSION['userid'] as well   ??

The below code works:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']))
{
    $userid2=$_REQUEST['id'];
}
else
{
echo "session id 1 value".$_SESSION['userid'];
    $userid2=$_SESSION['userid'];
}
```

Comment: If you found the solution, you can answer to your own question and validate it in order to change the status of this question.

Comment: Do you have global variables turned on?

Comment: if assigning to a var changes values elsewhere, then start looking if that var was ever defined as a reference somewhere. e.g. $userid &= $something_else.

Comment: Try: `ini_get('register_globals ');` to see if it is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `register_globals` turned on, which is a potential security hole (very easy to fall into as you've noticed), and a dead end (it's gone from 5.4).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals:

> Whether or not to register the EGPCS (Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server) variables as global variables.
>
> As of PHP 4.2.0, this directive defaults to off.
>
> Please read the security chapter on [Using register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) for related information.
>
> **Warning**
>
> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Thanks, that was turned on our hosting provider by default but no on our dev server. what a stupid setting though it's good that the community decided to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have made `$userid` a reference to the session value, maybe? I can more or less reproduce it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Put 10 in the session
$_SESSION['userid'] = 10;

// Get a reference to that session variable (note the `&`)
$userid = &$_SESSION['userid'];

// Increment
$userid++;

echo $_SESSION['userid'];  // 11
```